# What is the required data table structure for successful importation of data into Neo4j Aura using the data import tool?

Tags: graph-databases, neo4j-aura, data-importer

I have two data tables with seemingly equivalent structure that I'm trying to import into Neo4j Aura using the built-in data importer. When I import one of the tables, everything generates as expected. When I import the other, nodes are created, but the label I defined isn't assigned.

[Screenshot of both data imports side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJmJq.png)

I recreated the malfunctioning data multiple times using fewer and fewer fields, trying to eliminate every possible source of malfunction. I've examined the import report and Cypher code (which I admittedly don't understand very well). I ran the preview function and made sure all my mappings are verified with the green check. I've read the documentation on using the data import tool. Nothing has shed any light into what might be going on.

The table that imported correctly contains all the sorts of field names and values that I want to include in the malfunctioning table, so I would expect both to perform equivalently.

Answer (score 0):

To get the rest of the Labels to display, I had to go into the Perspective configurations in the Explore tab and manually add (again) each of the labels I had created in my Graph Model. In my case, the Labels were in a drop down list and when I selected them, the assignment was automatic - all my nodes became differentiated with their own color coding.

Note that the perspective generally doesn't display all the records in the database, so the counts below each label might give the impression that some records weren't assigned (super confusing, in my opinion), and some Labels that are assigned may not appear in the Nodes legend in the right panel at all if the In Scene option is selected. In my case, I could view all the Labels (even those that weren't visualized) by changing my selection to All.

To confirm that all the nodes were in fact imported, I went to the Query tab and used the Cypher code: Match (n) Return n. All the Labels and total node counts were displayed correctly in the Results Overview.